# Dúvidas sobre pusher do vue js

Tags: vue.js

Estou seguindo um tutorial que tem que digitar o seguinte comando para criar um projeto vue:

Ele criar uma pasta chamada music-db, em seguida ele digita esse comando estando dentro da pasta;

`vue init webpack frondend`

Ao digitar esse comando é criado somente uma pasta com o nome de **frondend**, e ao entrar dentro da pasta frondend existe outras pastas.

ai depois em seguida é digitado esse comando abaixo;

`yarn install`

E em seguida digita esse comando abaixo;

`yarn add vuex vuex-router-sync vue-router axios animate.css google-material-color material-design-icons laravel-echo pusher-js`

Depois desses comandos ele digita novamente esse comando:

`yarn install`

E em seguida ele sai da pasta frondend e entra em uma pasta com o nome API que está dentro da pasta music-db, isso no tutorial, porém essa pasta não foi criada no meu projeto.

Anteriormente quando eu executei o comando 
`vue init webpack frondend`

Ele tinha somente criado somente  a pasta frondend e nada mais, agora dentro da pasta music-db tem uma pasta API.

O que tem dentro da pasta api?
tem uma arquivos chamado .env

Lá ele pega uma senha  é uma num arquivo como esse abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele pega essa senha do pusher_app_key e coloca dentro do projeto vue.

Qual é minha dúvida?

- Como faço para criar essa pasta API dentro da pasta music-db?
- Será que errei em algum comando no tutorial acima?
- E para que serve o Pusher num projeto vue?

As perguntas parecem muito idiotas, mas é porque eu ainda estou apredendo e não tem ninguém para pedir ajuda sobre isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sou novo no StackOverflow, e não sei se entendi muito bem, mas tentarei ajudar.

- **Como faço para criar essa pasta API dentro da pasta music-db?**

**Resposta:** Provavelmente o tutorial é referente a uma aplicação em Vuejs2 e Laravel, no caso há duas pastas separadas, a "frondend" que é a aplicação front-end em Vuejs2, e a pasta "api" que é a pasta do back-end em Laravel. Não consegui verificar a criação da pasta api em realmente em nenhum momento do seu código. Se o tutorial for de vuejs, provavelmente ele está ensinando com o foco no front-end, e não está de fato explicando a criação e funcionamento do back-end. Se desejar criar um back-end do início, supondo que você já possui algumas] ferramentas necessárias instaladas, como o php 7.1, um editor que possua extensões compatíveis com Vuejs2 e Laravel, etc, citarei as com o foco no Laravel. Primeiramente é necessário o composer se não estiver ele instalado, pode verificar em [getcomposer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) (caso não conheça sobre o composer, ele é um gerenciador de dependências do php, procure saber mais). Em seguida, vá na documentação do [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5) e selecione a melhor maneira de criação de um novo projeto, recomendo pelo composer com o comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel api` (o último parâmetro é o nome da pasta). Feito isso, para executar a aplicação em um servidor local utilize o comando `php artisan serve`. Ele executará um servidor local na porta 8000. Após isto, deverá verificar sobre o que exatamente o front-end está consumindo da API, para você implementar todo o processo. O fluxo básico de um tutorial geralmente é criar um model utilizando o comando `php artisan make:model NomeDaClasse -m` (o "-m" é para criar a migration que irá se comunicar com banco de dados). Uma rota no arquivo api.php na pasta routes. Finalmente, crie um controller `php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource` (o "--resource" o laravel já disponibiliza todo o sistema de rotas de get, post, put e delete com apenas uma linha). Agora é só implementar de acordo com o front-end. Tudo pode ser encontrado na documentação do laravel.

- **Será que errei em algum comando no tutorial acima?**

**Resposta:** Não tenho como ter certeza absoluta mas creio que não. Um comando contendo `vue init webpack frondend` apenas inicializa um projeto Vuejs2, e não arquivos de um API em Laravel. No caso, o .env é o local onde é armazenado todas as variáveis de ambiente. Ele está pegando a senha para provavelmente sincronizar os eventos do pusher e possuir acesso em real-time da aplicação da API com o Vuejs2 (front-end).

- **E para que serve o Pusher num projeto vue?**

**Resposta:** Sinceramente, nunca utilizei, mas tentarei responder com base no pouco conhecimento que possuo. O Pusher no tutorial pode ser utilizado junto ao laravel-echo, que é uma biblioteca para realizar eventos em uma conexão de WebSocket. No caso do Vuejs2, pode ser necessário a sincronização da chave, para sincronizar em *real-time (live-update)* as telas do Vuejs2, ou seja, quando algum dado está atualizado no servidor, uma mensagem é enviada para conexão do WebSocket a fim de ser tratada pelo front-end. Basicamente é "disparar" eventos, onde você consegue compartilhar o mesmo nome do evento disparado no Laravel, do servidor, com sua aplicação cliente (front-end) em Vuejs2 , ou qualquer outra aplicação em javascript.

Espero ter ajudado.