# Ruoting com Laravel e VueJS

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

Estou iniciando com laravel e vue e estou tento uma dificuldade absurda em achar algo que mostre ou ensine como fazer routing usando laravel e vuejs. Quero criar uma simples aplicação SPA com Laravel e VueJS mas não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondi algo semelhante [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240928/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-pusher-do-vue-js/267261#267261) na primeira pergunta de outro membro. Tentarei ajudar com o que sei:

Primeiramente você precisará de um editor, como [Atom](https://atom.io/) ou [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), ou qualquer outro que suporte e tenha recursos para ambas as linguagens. Em seguida, deve possuir o [php](https://secure.php.net/downloads.php), recomendo a utilização do mais atualizado. É necessário o composer se não tiver ele instalado, pode verificar em [getcomposer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) (caso não conheça sobre o composer, ele é um gerenciador de dependências do php, procure saber mais).

- **Laravel**:

*"Vá na documentação do [laravel](https://laravel.com/) e selecione a melhor maneira de criação de um novo projeto, recomendo pelo composer com o comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel api` (o último parâmetro é o nome da pasta). Feito isso, para executar a aplicação em um servidor local utilize o comando `php artisan serve`. Ele executará um servidor local na porta 8000."* (informado na outra pergunta).

No caso das [rotas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing), há uma pasta routes com o arquivo api.php. Nela ficará todo o seu sistema de rotas do laravel. Para criar uma nova, basta adicionar um novo `Route::metodoHTTPQueDeseja('pathDaApi','Controller@metodoDoController');`. No laravel, há algo chamado *resource*, onde a sintaxe é assim: `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`. Ele já cria todos os métodos que geralmente são utilizados geralmente em CRUDS com uma só linha, ou seja, é o equivalente a criar uma rota de get para tod

Para não criar todas as rotas, pode se especificar com o array *only* para somente estes métodos ou *except* para excluir alguns métodos. Exemplo abaixo:

`Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController', ['only' => [
    'index', 'show'
]]);`

`Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController', ['except' => [
    'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'
]]);`

Todos os métodos do resource de acordo com a documentação do laravel:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao chamar no front-end uma requisição que acesse alguma rota, um método e o controller é especificado, logo deverá sempre ter o controller criado. Para criar um controller, o comando é `php artisan make:controller NomeDoController --resource` (o "--resource" é para agilizar caso pretenda utilizar a rota de resource descrita anteriormente). Assim você conseguirá acessar os comandos.

Para realizar um CRUD, é necessário um banco de dados, um model que o controller irá trabalhar e uma migration. Para criar um model utilize o comando `php artisan make:model NomeDaClasse -m` (o "-m" é para criar a migration que irá se comunicar com banco de dados).
Agora basta realizar a implementação em cada um dos métodos criados. Não se esqueça de retornar na resposta fora um objeto, o código de estado do HTTP corretamente para cada situação.

Tente ler a documentação também caso tenha problemas.
Procure saber mais também sobre Model Binding, [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections) e validação de [Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) caso não saiba. É algo que facilita e agiliza o desenvolvimento. Também é interessante que futuramente aplique testes e TDD, utilizando provavelmente o `phpunit` e classes de [Factory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing).

- **Vuejs2**

No caso do Vuejs2, primeiramente você precisa ter o [Nodejs/npm](https://nodejs.org/en/). Para realizar a instalação de um novo projeto, execute os comandos segundo a própria documentação do Vuejs2:

```
install vue-cli
$ npm install --global vue-cli
create a new project using the "webpack" template
$ vue init webpack my-project
# install dependencies and go!
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

O Vuejs2 por si só é apenas um framework front-end baseado em componentes. Porém, com a utilização do `vue-cli`, ele já vem com o `vue-router`, no caso o sistema de rotas que consiste em sua dúvida principal. Onde está escrito my-project, é o nome do projeto. `npm run dev` irá executar a aplicação local. Eu recomendo a utilização do [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/). É um framework para Vuejs2 com material design com uma ótima documentação, sempre atualizando, e bem simples e ótimo de se utilizar em minha humilde opinião. Se optar por utilizar, deverá inicializar com o [Vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) ou instalar via npm e importá-lo em seu App.vue ou qualquer outro arquivo de configuração `.js`.

No caso do sistema de rotas, ele está localizado no path *src/routes/index.js*. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello
    },
    {
      path: '/primeiraRota',
      name: 'PrimeiraRota',
      component: PrimeiraRota
    }
  ]
})
```

O atributo `name` é opcional. Pode também ser passado *props* para o componente nas rotas e acessar com mais algum parâmetro, para isto o path deverá conter  `path: '/primeiraRota/:parametro'`. Um componente que possua seu path em uma rota também pode ter "filhos", e seus filhos podem ter outros filhos, e assim por diante. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
{
  path: '/',
  redirect: 'teste',
  component: Teste,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/testeFilho',
      component: TesteFilho,
      props: { teste: 'name' },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          component: Tabela
        },
        {
          path: 'novo',
          component: Formulario
        },
        {
          path: 'edicao/:id',
          component: Modal
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

O funcionamento é o seguinte, ao acessar pelo navegador em uma rota, como por exemplo `localhost:8080/#/primeiraRota` ele irá "chamar" o componente "PrimeiraRota" e executar seu *lifecycle (created, mounted, etc)*. Isto por causa do `<router-view></router-view>` que se encontra em seu App.vue. Pode ser utilizado vários *router-view* dentro de um mesmo projeto, mediante sua necessidade e arquitetura utilizada.

Há como também um componente acessar diretamente por links diretamente no html,
 como no exemplo abaixo:

`<router-link :to="variavelNoData">Link para rota</router-link>`

O `:to` pode ser tanto uma variável que exista em seu `data ()`, que é preenchido dinamicamente com o "path" desejado, ou sem os ":" e apenas o "path" diretamente como uma *string*.

**Observação:** Pode haver alguns erros pois não realizei todo o procedimento, apenas digitei sem a verificação prévia, portanto peço que verifique sempre junto a documentação ao realizar o processo, e se algo estiver errado, me corrija por gentileza.

Mesmo uma aplicação básica, não tenho como saber seu nível de conhecimento tanto em programação quanto nestas linguagens, e se torna um processo longo. Tentei deixar o mais enxuto possível focando mais nas rotas mas acabou ficando um pouco longo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Show de bola tua explicação. Ainda não coloquei em prática mas vou testar. Utilizo o laravel já e agora estou tentando criar aplicações spa. Acho mais bonita a forma de se comportar sem a necessidade de recarregar a página. Vue estou no início da aprendizagem mas achando super fácil. Mto mais fácil do que angular 2. Enfim, muito obrigado!